# How can I sync/transfer only photos from a specific album from iPhone to iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud

I have a large photo library in iCloud. I also have an older iPad that doesn't have much storage space. My iCloud photos use up way more storage than my iPad has available. Currently, the iPad is not connected to my iCloud storage for photos.

I would like to sync a selection of my iCloud photos to my iPad. On my iPhone, these photos are in an album.

I don't have a Mac computer.

How can I sync/transfer only photos from a specific album from iPhone to iPad??

Answer (score 0):

You could get a lightning to USB adapter and getting the 16 GB or 64 GB or 128GB Usb depending on the size, plugging in the usb and copying specific files you want. Then Plug it into your iPad and copy files, create the album and select your files which you just copied, into your album you just created.

an alternate solution is using airdrop. make sure bluetooth is turned on in both the devices, change the airdrop setting from contacts only to everyone in both the devices. after that you can select the files, Share > Airdrop > Your iPad device.create the album and select your files which you just copied, into your album you just created.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Air drop is a possibility. Is there any way I can use iCloud in this situation at all? Instead of making physical copies, just pointing to the photos?

Comment: hmmm i don't have an ipad with me at the moment, maybe you could download files from icloud through browser and add to the ablum.